# Add item to cache without removing entire collection

Tags: c#, caching

so using The .NET System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache object, how should I and what is the best way of updating a cache which is a dictionary where I want to insert an item into that dictionary?

I don't want to get the dictionary, add the item to the dictionary, remove the existing key/dictionary from the cache and then readd it. Is there a better more elegant way of doing this?

So just to make it clear, I have a dictionary full of items (Dictionary). 
This dictionary, is added into the MemoryCache and a key is assigned to it.

I then want to be able to add an item into this dictionary which gets reflected back into the cache.

Many thanks!

Comment: I think you can just get the dictionary from the cache, add an item to the dictionary, and you're done.

Answer (score 2):

Think there needs to be a differentiation between Dictionary and MemoryCache. The need for MemoryCache is that of "expiration" of data and to a slew of shortfalls in the .NET Cache object itself. Are you drawing on the real benefit of a MemoryCache by embedding a Dictionary into it?

Outside of that, there is no alternative, to adding or updating an Object within an Object without touching it.

Comment: Thanks Dane. Basically the cache will hold different types of data. sometimes just a List<T> or a Dictionary<T, U>. It just depends on the type of data/context. In this case, for this particular scenario, I need access to the dictionary from the cache so I can add an item to it. It seems that the only way to do this would be to get the dictionary item from cache, place a lock around it (MT safe), check to see if the item does not exist and if not then add the item in the dictionary and finally do a MemoryCache.Set(...).

Comment: @Ahmedilyas - why do you need to do the MemoryCache.Set? Does getting the dictionary from the cache remove it from the cache? Also, you may want to look at ConcurrentDictionary.

Comment: @Hatchet - no it does not remove it from the cache but the cache does need to get updated once you get the item from the cache.

Comment: @Ahmedilyas - the cache contains a reference to the dictionary object, and you get the reference when you get it from the cache. If you then change the internals of the dictionary (like add an item), the cache is still pointing to that same dictionary, which is now a little different inside. The reference doesn't change, but the state of what it points to can change. This is why you have to consider multi-thread issues when you store mutable objects in a global cache. Two threads could both get a reference to it and try to change it at the same time. The cache doesn't need to get updated.

Comment: yes of course. reference types.... sorry. been heavily into VB6 code and migrating to C#. good point. it is why I am using a lock (and will use concurrent dictionary instead) to make sure it is MT safe when it comes to writing. thanks Hatchet.